# New Instance Of A Form Overwrites The Existing Form Variable Declaration

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, instance, dockpanel

I'm using Weifen Lous's Dock Panel Suite. In my code, I'm creating new instances of a form for my text editor which I dock in my application's main form. MDI parent-child stuffs. I'm having a problem every time I reinitialize the variable that holds an instance of my form.

**Here's my code:**

```
Private Sub AddTabPage()

        Try

            Editor = New frmEditor
            Editor.Text = "New Tab"
            Editor.Show(dpMain, DockState.Document)

        Catch ex As Exception

            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Message", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)

        End Try

    End Sub
```

As you can see, the code above is called every time a user decides to add a tab on my text editor. What the code does is create a new instance of the form which is docked in the main form of my application.

**Now the problem is here:**

```
Private Sub Editor_ColorToolStripMenuItem_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Editor_ColorToolStripMenuItem.Click

    Dim CR As New ColorDialog
    CR.ShowDialog()
    CType(Editor.rtbCode, RichTextBox).SelectionColor = CR.Color

End Sub
```

In the tool strip menu item above, I am calling the form variable I created using the `AddTabPage` sub routine: (`CType(Editor...`). This works fine if there is only a single form. But when I try to add another tab; that is call the `AddTabPage` again which re-initializes the `Editor` form variable, I can no longer change the color of the text written on the previously created tab/form(first tab/form). I believe this occurs because `Editor` is being reinitialized every time I add a form. The previous tab/form created is losing its data/controls(first tab/form)? I'm not sure, but something like that happens.

Now, what I want is to achieve is that every time I create a tab/form, I will still be able to change the color of the texts written on every tab I will create. How will I prevent the data/controls of the previous form from being overwritten/gone(I'm sorry, I don't know the proper term to use.)

I can solve the problem by declaring a predefined number of form variables then using a switch statement to determine the current focused form. But I think there is a better way to do this. I want to have unlimited tab/forms in my dock panel.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind. I solved the problem.

To access the form I want to dock, I used this code:

```
dpMain.ActiveDocument.DockHandler.Form.Controls.Item(0)
```

That way, I wont be obliged to explicitly use `Editor`.

**EDIT:**

`Item(0)` is the index of a `RichTextBox` in the form.